Solution to ODE doesn't blow up to infinity
The problem is
Show that for any $a \gt 0$, The boundary value problem
$y'' = y^2, y(-1)=a, y(1)=a$
has a solution.
To prove this I defined y_b to be the unique solution to the ODE
$y(0)=b, y'(0)=0, y'' =y^2$
If $b = 0$ then we have that $y_b = 0$ and so $y_0(1)<a$ so we downshoot $a$.
and if we take $b=a$ then $y_b \ge y_b(0)=a$ as $0$ is a global minimum($y''$ is positive and thus $y'$ is increasing) so $y_b(1)\ge a$ we overshoot. Now because the solutions are variing continouasly somewhere between $0$ and $a$ we had a solution $y_b$ such that $y_b(1)=1$. Now notice that $y_b$ is even function as $y_b(-x)$ stasfies the same exact ODE as $y_b$ so they are equal.
And we are done. Kind of. My problem is I am not sure how to prove that $y_b$ doesnt blow up to infinity before $1$. So my question is how to prove it doesn't?
